# How to create two Vue routes pointing to the same component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I need to create two Vue routes `/items/:id` and `/items/new`.

What I did so far:

```
{ path: '/items/:id', component: Item },
{ path: '/items/new', component: Item },
```

In the context of the project I am working on, `Item` component is responsible for viewing an existing item and creating a new one.

Is there a way to merge the two config lines in a single one? like (pseudo code)

```
{ path: '/items/(:id || new)', component: Item }
```

Comment: In my opinion you don't need to create a separate route for ```'/items/new'```, you can pass the [```params```](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#navigate-to-a-different-location) value as **"new"** when you need.

Comment: when setting "new" to ":mappingId", we lose the semantic, meaning "new" isn't an id.

Comment: I said in **my opinion**, means that if I wanted to write codes for that. Also if your problem is semantic meaning of ```params``` , try to change the name of ```params``` from ```id``` to something meaningful, for example ```toBeShown```!